# Rename sheet name to table name

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I imported a bunch of data into my Excel from SQL. So I have a bunch of sheets like so:

[image]

Each sheet has a table name that I can view in the table view area here:

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way to mass re-name the sheets to what the table name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Sub RenameSheetToTableName()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not tbl Is Nothing Then ws.Name = tbl.Name
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: In a module in the VBA Editor